# C++: Do I need to use cin.get() before I use cin.ignore?

Tags: c++, cin

Does `cin.ignore(100,'\n')` work if I just use standard cin through the stream?

Example:

```
cin >> temp;  //enter key input
if(cin.fail())
{
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(100,'\n');
}
```

or do I have to use cin.get()?

Example:

```
temp=cin.get();
if(cin.fail())
{
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(100,'\n');
}
```

Or will these codes produce identical results?

Comment: Have you tried to just execute it, and see what happens? Also, what is the desired behavior, and what is the type of `temp`?

Comment: yes I have, unfortunately both don't seem to be working the way I like, hence the question. temp is an `int` so when users mash on keyboard, it should clear the error. It's working as that but it prints an extra newline and halts until I press return again.

Comment: Then please describe how you would like it to behave.

Comment: @space edited my comment above

Comment: Please provide a complete compilable and runnable example, so we can reconstruct your error. There is no printing in your current example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, stupid me, I made a function to call the clearing

```
void clear()
{
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(100,'\n');
}
```

and in my program, it called function `clear()` more than once. In the cases where `clear()` was called twice in a row without input from cin, it prompted for input in a blank line.

I'm guessing this is what caused it.

Comment: follow up question: Is there a more efficient way to clear input of garbage?

Comment: No, clear() just clears some status flags. There is no harm in calling it twice.

Comment: sorry, confusion, my function named clear() not cin.clear().. so calling my clear() function makes it prompt for another newline